# android - save an image into gallery

Tags: android, image, camera, android-camera, gallery

I am attempting to save an image into the android gallery, but unfortunately, it is not showing up.

My picture callback is as follows:

```
Camera.PictureCallback mPicture = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            File pictureFileDir = getDir("images", 0);

            if (!pictureFileDir.exists() && !pictureFileDir.mkdirs()) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Can't create directory to save image.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;

            }

            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyymmddhhmmss");
            String date = dateFormat.format(new Date());
            String photoFile = "Picture_" + date + ".jpg";

            String filename = pictureFileDir.getPath() + File.separator + photoFile;

            File pictureFile = new File(filename);

            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                fos.write(data);
                fos.close();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "New Image saved:" + photoFile,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                //Insert image into gallery
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + pictureFile.getPath());
                MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), bitmap, photoFile , "My Image");
            } catch (Exception error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image could not be saved.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            //...
        }
 };
```

I believe that the image is saved properly in the app data, but it does not show up in the gallery.

My app requires these two permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Unfortunately, this code still does not work. Is there anything incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply an incorrect filepath.

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + pictureFile.getPath());
```

needs to me

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pictureFile.getPath());
```